Is がないだろうか different from ではないというか?
"こには入ってもらえないけど、職員用カフェテラスが空いているからそこでご挨拶しましょう!"
(カフェテラス。他の人間の目や耳がないだろうか)
The characters need to meet a friend. However, as the work in a police station, they can't invite the friend inside. So he says this. The protagonist then thinks the second line.
How should がないだろうか here be taken? as a "I wonder if there wont' be"?

Xがあるだろうか, Xがあるかな and so on express neutral or slightly hopeful wondering ("I wonder if there is X").
On the other hand, Xがないだろうか, Xがないかな and similar expressions often carry a doubtful nuance, and are more like "(I wonder,) Isn't there X?". This suggests that the speaker thinks X is likely to exist, and it can be used regardless of whether X is desirable or undesirable.

近くに銀行がないだろうか
Isn't there a bank nearby?
近くに監視カメラがないだろうか
Isn't there a security camera nearby?
(監視カメラ may be undesirable to the speaker)

